# Inconsistency with lib vendor/markbaker

Tags: yii2

I am using Yii2 and after updating the framework (composer update), the following error appeared:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ‘.’, expecting ‘&’ or variable
>   in vendor/markbaker\complex\classes\src\operations\add.php on line 18

[image]

Does anyone know what this is about?

Comment: what php version are you running?

Comment: see if running `composer check-platform-reqs` helps you identify the issue

Comment: My PHP version is 5.5.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vendor dependency markbaker/complex that throws this syntax error simply requires php 5.6

you need to either update your environment or try an older version of that library